# Missing Element Confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, fbml, fbjs

I'm creating a script that produces a content locker after X number of minutes. The problem is, the content within likeButton will not display. The modal popup displays fine, as does the title and instructions. Just not the likeButton content. If I take the code block out of the timer, it works. I'm a little confused. Any idea whats going on?

```
var title           = 'Please Press Like';
var instructions    = 'Like our videos? Join our fanpage. It takes 1 second.';
var lockDelay       = 100;  // 1200000 = 20 Minutes

/* STOP EDITING */
var boxy;

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Create the like button
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Create the like button
        var likeButton = '<div id="likeButton"><fb:like href="" send="false" layout="box_count" width="70" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like></div>';

        // Display the modal
        boxy = new Boxy('<p id="instructions">' + instructions + '</p>' + likeButton, {
            title: title,
            modal: true,
            closeable: false,
        });
    }, lockDelay);

    // Close modal after user likes
    $('#likeButton').mouseover(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {boxy.hide()}, 3000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var title           = 'Please Press Like';
var instructions    = 'Like our videos? Join our fanpage. It takes 1 second.';
var lockDelay       = 100;  // 1200000 = 20 Minutes

/* STOP EDITING */
var boxy;

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Create the like button
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Create the like button
        var likeButton = '<div id="likeButton"><fb:like href="" send="false" layout="box_count" width="70" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like></div>';

        // Display the modal
        boxy = new Boxy('<p id="instructions">' + instructions + '</p>' + likeButton, {
            title: title,
            modal: true,
            closeable: false,
        });

        // Close modal after user likes
        $('#likeButton').mouseover(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {boxy.hide()}, 3000);
        });
    }, lockDelay);

});
```

Comment: Exactly. Anonymous function creates the button after 100ms. Script actually tries to bind event before element is created, therefore it does not work, since element doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't think moving the mouseover will make a difference as the mouseover event is hiding the modal, not the content within the likeButton variable. I've tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: @usoban changing it to 10 seconds makes no difference it still doesn't work.

Comment: look at katspaugh's answer. It'll init the button. However, without the modification ShankarSangoli provided, the modal will not close. So actually you've got two errors :)

Comment: The point is the button should be available in the DOM before Jquery tries to attach mouserover event.